# PostgreSQL importing from folder

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, postgresql, sql

I lost my ubuntu partition (12.04) and I've installed the ubuntu 14.04, I could save my database files from postgreSQL v9.1, but now I'm with a problem how can I import this data base and my settings to this postgreSQL that came with Ubuntu (14.04) that is the 9.3.4.

- UPDATE *

I've installed a VirtualBox Machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and installed PostgreSQL 9.1, I've copied the folder `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main` to the Ubuntu_VirtualBox, I could start the server (just a tip: `chown postgres:postgres 9.1` and `chmod -R 700 9.1`) and I did the `pg_dump -Ft database > database.tar` I exported the sql file to my work ubuntu and tried to `pg_restore -Ft -C database.tar` it show up everything that is on the file at my screen but if I run `psql -l` the database that I've imported don't appear, so I came back to the Ubuntu_Virtualbox and did `pg_dump database > database.sql` and tried to import it doing a new database and import using the `phppgadmin` this appeared to me.

```
Erro de SQL:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM () AS sub
                                       ^

No bloco:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM () AS sub
```

Well, in virtualbox I've edited `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and set the configuration `upload_max_filesize = 30M` from `2M` to `30m` and I did the export again using the phppgadmin with the option data and estrcture type sql and I could import it.

I'm still testing...

Comment: Do you not have backups?

Comment: You have to install 9.1.

Comment: My last back was from 1 week past the incident, so many things lost :( --- Craig Ringer, and after, put the folder in there and make a backup?

Comment: Yes, install 9.1 along side 9.3, connect up the old DB, pg_dump and then import into 9.3. The standard process for major version point upgrades in pg. Then you can uninstall 9.1 if you want.

Comment: I've installed 9.1, connected the old DB, did the backup and I tried to import but it don't appear in my PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

### For your first try when the DB was not created :

`pg_dump database` will create all the SQL statements to recreate tables, indexes, functions, ... and data but without the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

You use `pg_restore` with `-C` to recreate the database, which only works if you also give the name of the DB using the `-d` switch, like this :

```
pg_restore -Ft -C -d database database.tar
```